# How to switch the capitals characters transform in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

The SQL editor in DBeaver has this unsupportable feature of transforming all capital characters into lower case. This happens as you type, the most schizophrenic thing.

I have searched in the menus and the Preferences dialogue, but I can not find the setting to this feature. How can I switch it off?

Comment: Given that capitalizing SQL keywords is considered best-practice; e.g.: SELECT * FROM Country WHERE etc.., why would DBeaver convert to lower-case by default? Seems an odd decision... am I missing something?

Comment: No idea why they do this, but this is very annoying!

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Got to *Preferences* > *General* > *Editors* > *SQL Editor* > *SQL Formatting*. Then over under *Auto Format* there is a box for *Convert Keyword Case*.

[image]

Comment: Is this in the enterprise edition only? Because I don't have options for the SQL editor. EDIT: Nevermind I found it when searching for SQL Formatting, but it won't show up in the list otherwise.

Comment: In DBeaver version 6.2.2, this option is available at Preferences > Database > Editors > SQL Editor > SQL Completion > Auto Format section > Concert keyword case

Comment: In DBeaver 6.3.1, this option is also available, but should also check with the setting as answered by @Joel below. Otherwise, it dose not work.

Comment: In DBeaver v21.1.5, the option is moved to: `Preferences > Database > Editors > SQL Editor > Code Editor > Auto format > Convert keyword case`

Comment: In DBeaver v22.0.5, the option is moved to `Preferences > Editors > SQL Editor > Formatting > Settings > Keyword case`. It's almost as if they don't want us to find it …

Comment: In DBeaver Version 22.2.3 has moved to `Preferences > Editors > SQL Editor > Code Editor > Autor format`

Answer (score 43):

My two cents, for Version 7.0.1.2:

- Preferences -> DBeaver -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> SQL Formating ->
  **Keyword case**

You can dictate this behaviour. Didn't test for older versions but it seems to be there for a while.

[image]

Comment: **Window** -> Preferences -> DBeaver -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> SQL Formating -> Keyword case

In the interest of full instructions (and because as a dbeaver noob I struggled to find 'preferences' )

Comment: in 21.1.1 it's in:  "Formatting" instead of "SQL Formatting".

Also you can search for 'upper' in the filter text to find it

Comment: This option does not seem to force lowercase for uppercase named tables and columns. For example, if the database has table TABLEXYZ and you type in table..., Dbeaver will force uppercase on autocomplete regardless of the keyword case being set to lower. Some of our data eng live for ALL UPPERCASE which makes this a bit annoying.

Answer (score 39):

In the new versioning (>= 21.1.4) this feature has been moved to `Window > Preferences > Editors > SQL Editor > Formatting`. Change `Keyword case` to `Upper` and apply changes.

[image]

Comment: The same for 23.1.3.

Comment: The same for 23.2.5

Answer (score 23):

For *DBeaver 6.2.4* I've found it in:

1. *Window → Preferences → Database → Editors → SQL Editor → SQL Formatting / Keyword case option*
   [Keyword case option1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBDzu.png)
2. *Window → Preferences → Database → Editors → SQL Editor → SQL Completion/ Convert keyword case option*
   [Keyword case option2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySXkz.png)

---

For *DBeaver 7.0.2*:

- *Window → Preferences → DBeaver → Editors → SQL Editor → SQL Completion/ Convert keyword case option*
  [image: Convert case option]

Answer (score 8):

As of `DBeaver` 5.3.5 the **Convert keyword case** toggle can be found under:

- `Window > Preferences` and then at `Database > Editors > SQL Editor > SQL Completion`.

Comment: Is it possible to make keyword uppercase and columns, tables lowercase?
ex: `SELECT first_name,last_name FROM actor;`

Answer (score 6):

Through `DBeaver` > 6.2.1, the `Convert keyword case` can be enabled or disabled through the following sequence:

- `Preferences` -> `DBeaver` -> `Editors` -> `SQL Editor` -> `SQL Completion`

With new versions now is:

- `Preferences` -> `Database` -> `Database Editors` -> `SQL Editor` -> `Code Editor`

Comment: For the new version, in the "Code Editor", you need to uncheck the "Convert keyword case".

Answer (score 5):

On version 21.1.3, it was necessary to change in two places.

1. Window -> Preferences -> SQLEditor -> Code Completion -> InsertCase(Change the pattern to UpperCase)
2. Window - Preferences -> SQLEditor -> Code Editor -> Convert keyword case(Unset it)

Answer (score 2):

In version 21.3.3.202201221033 it's under Window > Preferences > Editors > SQL Editor > Code Editor > Auto format > Convert keyword case

Answer (score 1):

The interface is slightly different in version `7.2.2`, if set to default is enabled it will be lowercase. To change it to uppercase:

- `preferences` -> `Database Editors` -> `SQL Editor` -> `SQL Formatting` -> **Keyword Case**

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same doubt, so I found this link:
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Shortcuts

In this document there are a lot of shortcuts, including CTRL+SHIFT+Y to make strings in lowercase.